# CakePHP: How secure post method is?

Tags: php, cakephp, post, cakephp-2.0

I heard that post method is not secure.

If it's not secured, then how can i make it secured.

Which method should i use to get more security ?

In CakePHP, I use $this->request->data, this returns the data from post method.

What's the alternative to this, if post method is not secured ?

Comment: Where did you hear that post is not "secure"? What do you mean by "secure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you heard about post being insecure and I'm not really sure what you are afraid of (Could you clarify, please?).
If you use post, you can be sure that the data came in via a `POST` request (and not a `GET`).

If you are afraid of someone listening in between your server and the client's browser, it does not make much of a difference which method you use. Both can be intercepted. Use POST/GET via HTTPS instead of HTTP to prevent this.

Comment: How can i use https instead of http ?

Comment: Buy an SSL certificate and set up your server to use it. Then use https://www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com

Comment: How can i buy SSL certificate and how can i set up server to use it? Which server are you talking about?

Comment: @guru: You can use money for buying things. Also [Google: buy ssl certificate](https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+ssl+certificate) and [Google: how to set up SSL on webserver](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+up+ssl+webserver)

Comment: The website is hosted. I don't have permission on that webserver. I can only upload the website with ftp client.

Comment: @guru Then ask your webhost/provider to do this for you.